# glm - Decompose mat4 into translation and rotation?

Tags: matrix, orientation, translation, decomposition

For purposes of lerping I need to decompose a 4x4 matrix into a quaternion and a vec3.
Grabbing the quaternion is simple, as you can just pass the matrix into the constructor, but I can't find a way to grab the translation.
Surely there must be a way?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like glm 0.9.6 supports matrix decomposition
http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/api/a00204.html

```
#include <glm/gtx/matrix_decompose.hpp>

glm::mat4 transformation; // your transformation matrix.
glm::vec3 scale;
glm::quat rotation;
glm::vec3 translation;
glm::vec3 skew;
glm::vec4 perspective;
glm::decompose(transformation, scale, rotation, translation, skew, perspective);
```

Comment: The documentation is a bit outdated on that one (even for current v0.9.7), you need to include <glm/gtx/matrix_decompose.hpp> instead of <glm/gtx/decomposition.hpp> for it to work.

Comment: It should be noted that if all you want is the translation vector, this approach is incredibly computationally inefficient. @kerim's answer below will be much faster.

Answer (score 37):

`glm::vec3(m[3])` is the position vector(assuming `m` is `glm::mat4`)

Comment: I think it's worth explaining _why_ this works. A translation matrix is just a 4x4 identity matrix with the positions in the fourth column (with a `1` in the fourth row of that). In GLM, a `mat4` is a 4-array of `vec4`, where each `vec4` represents one column; arrays are zero-indexed, so `[3]` gets the fourth column. Then `glm::vec3(...)` converts it to a vec3, discarding the fourth (unused) part, and giving you just the translation distance.

Answer (score 23):

At version glm-0.9.8.1 you have to include:

`#include <glm/gtx/matrix_decompose.hpp>`

To use it:

```
glm::mat4 transformation; // your transformation matrix.
glm::vec3 scale;
glm::quat rotation;
glm::vec3 translation;
glm::vec3 skew;
glm::vec4 perspective;
glm::decompose(transformation, scale, rotation, translation, skew,perspective);
```

Keep in mind that the resulting quaternion in not correct.
It returns its conjugate!

To fix this add this to your code:

`rotation=glm::conjugate(rotation);`

Comment: Thannk a bunch, really strange API

Comment: How did you figure out that the quaternion returned is the conjugate? It doesn't say anything in the documentation

Comment: You can test by composing a transformation matrix of your choice and then perform decomposition to assert the values.

P.S.The conjugate of a quaternion represents its inverse rotation.

Comment: The conjugation bug was fixed in 9.9.0: https://godbolt.org/z/9Yqd33veG

Answer (score 11):

I figured I'd post an updated and complete answer for 2019. Credit where it's due, this is based off valmo's answer, includes some items from Konstantinos Roditakis's answer as well as some additional info I ran into.

Anyway, as of version 0.9.9 you can still use the experimental matrix decomposition: https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00518.html

First, and the part I am adding because I don't see it anywhere else, is that you will get an error unless you define the following before the include below:

```cpp
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL
```

Next, you have to include:

```cpp
#include <glm/gtx/matrix_decompose.hpp>
```

Finally, an example of use:

```cpp
glm::mat4 transformation; // your transformation matrix.
glm::vec3 scale;
glm::quat rotation;
glm::vec3 translation;
glm::vec3 skew;
glm::vec4 perspective;
glm::decompose(transformation, scale, rotation, translation, skew,perspective);
```

Also, the Quaternion, as stated in Konstantinos Roditakis's answer, is indeed incorrect and can be fixed by applying the following:

```cpp
rotation = glm::conjugate(rotation);
```

Answer (score 7):

I made my own decompose function that doesn't need "skew" and "perspective" components.

```cpp
void decomposeMtx(const glm::mat4& m, glm::vec3& pos, glm::quat& rot, glm::vec3& scale)
{
    pos = m[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        scale[i] = glm::length(vec3(m[i]));
    const glm::mat3 rotMtx(
        glm::vec3(m[0]) / scale[0],
        glm::vec3(m[1]) / scale[1],
        glm::vec3(m[2]) / scale[2]);
    rot = glm::quat_cast(rotMtx);
}
```

If you don't need scale either, it can be further simplified:

```cpp
void decomposeMtx(const glm::mat4& m, glm::vec3& pos, glm::quat& rot)
{
    pos = m[3];
    rot = glm::quat_cast(m);
}
```

Comment: Hey...this is underrataed ... seems to work well. Thank you.
The version of glm i'm on seems to give bad results - wrong, with some e-16 style stuff, despite inputting just a clean scaling matrix on the diagnol + single translation... I think decompose has a bug or maybe doesn't make certain assumptions about the matrix here maybe that end up making this version of it more stable.  

I'd appreciate an explanation of why this decompose seems to produce unstable results if anyone seems to know yet this one seems to work better?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for being late. Actually the reason you have to conjugate the result quat is wrong substraction order of matrix components when calculating x,y,z components of the quaternion.

[Here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm) is an explanation and sample code of how it should be.

So basically in glm, decompose() method, matrix_decompose.inl file:

We have :

```
    orientation.x = root * (Row[1].z - Row[2].y);
    orientation.y = root * (Row[2].x - Row[0].z);
    orientation.z = root * (Row[0].y - Row[1].x);
```

When it should be:

```
    orientation.x = root * (Row[2].y - Row[1].z);
    orientation.y = root * (Row[0].z - Row[2].x);
    orientation.z = root * (Row[1].x - Row[0].y);
```

Also [see this](https://github.com/jpkinney/meshmorph/blob/master/Wm4Quaternion.inl) impl which looks very close to the one found in GLM,but which is correct one.